# How to check duplicate entry before inserting to database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function import_excel(){
    if (!$_FILES["file"]["name"]) {
        echo "Please upload excel file !";
    } else {
        $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
        foreach ($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
            $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
            for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
                $username = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $email = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $address = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $contact_no = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue();
                $data[] = array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'address ' => $address ,
                    'contact_no' => $contact_no,
                );
            }
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('excel_files', $data);
    }
}
```

First I import the excel file it save into DB, but the second time I want to import again the excel but have new 4 data in excel, I wonder the 4 new data I want to upload in database no need to duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**ON DUPLICATE KEY UDPATE**

and

**$this->db->get_compiled_insert()**

should do the trick.

See: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#inserting-data

---

With plain SQL you **could** use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.

F.e.

```
-- Note: im asuming you got the email unique in the table.
INSERT INTO mytable (`username`, `email`, `address`, `contact_no`) 
VALUES (:name, :email, :address, :contact)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `username` = :name, 
    `address` = :address, 
    `contact_no` = :contact
;
```

The example above still would update the values (name, address and contact_no).

Or, if you dont want that, you could let update just a date,
or just do the "id trick": `` `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = `id` `` and nothing changes.

---

Not tested, but from the docu you can get the SQL like

```
$sql = $this->db->set_insert_batch($data)->get_compiled_insert('excel_files');
// or set() ?
// $sql = $this->db->set($data)->get_compiled_insert('excel_files');
```

and now append the

```
$sql .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...";
```

and then ofc execute the query like

```
$this->db->query($sql);
```

---

Note: i did not found a `usert_batch` or `save` (insert||update).
*The name "upsert" is often used to let insert or update if exists.*
*Same with "save" - create, update, save (does both).*